# How to “flatten” or “collapse” a 1D mysql table into 2D?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id  -  name  -  value
1   -  shoes - 21
1   -  gloves - 5
2   -  shoes - 23
2   -  gloves - 3
```

I want it to be converted to a table like this:

```
id  -  shoes  - gloves
1   -  21     - 5
2   -  23     - 3
```

Is it possible to do it with one query in Mysql?
I also want the name of columns to be generated from the `name` column in the 1st table.

Comment: Check:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: Also, consider handling such display related issues in your application code.

Comment: You can look at Dynamic SQL based solutions here: http://webdevzoom.com/dynamic-pivot-table-using-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `join` like this:

```
SELECT main.id, s.name AS shoes, g.name AS gloves
FROM tbl AS main
LEFT JOIN tbl s ON main.id = s.id
LEFT JOIN tbl g ON main.id = g.id
```